# Bootstrap organizar estructura HTML de 3 columnas moviendo posiciones sin duplicar HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

Tengo una estructura HTML en Bootstrap, esta consta de 3 columnas, por lo que debe estar en la versión de escritorio.

[image: Image 1]

Necesito que en la versión móvil sea así, arranque algunas características que permitan hacer esto?

[image: Image 2]

```css
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2017 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/*!
 * Generated using the Bootstrap Customizer (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/?id=9721a343505a7604c1b8fea06ac4fc30)
 * Config saved to config.json and https://gist.github.com/9721a343505a7604c1b8fea06ac4fc30
 *//*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 *//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace, monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:bold}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg')}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.glyphicon-asterisk:before{content:"\002a"}.glyphicon-plus:before{content:"\002b"}.glyphicon-euro:before,.glyphicon-eur:before{content:"\20ac"}.glyphicon-minus:before{content:"\2212"}.glyphicon-cloud:before{content:"\2601"}.glyphicon-envelope:before{content:"\2709"}.glyphicon-pencil:before{content:"\270f"}.glyphicon-glass:before{content:"\e001"}.glyphicon-music:before{content:"\e002"}.glyphicon-search:before{content:"\e003"}.glyphicon-heart:before{content:"\e005"}.glyphicon-star:before{content:"\e006"}.glyphicon-star-empty:before{content:"\e007"}.glyphicon-user:before{content:"\e008"}.glyphicon-film:before{content:"\e009"}.glyphicon-th-large:before{content:"\e010"}.glyphicon-th:before{content:"\e011"}.glyphicon-th-list:before{content:"\e012"}.glyphicon-ok:before{content:"\e013"}.glyphicon-remove:before{content:"\e014"}.glyphicon-zoom-in:before{content:"\e015"}.glyphicon-zoom-out:before{content:"\e016"}.glyphicon-off:before{content:"\e017"}.glyphicon-signal:before{content:"\e018"}.glyphicon-cog:before{content:"\e019"}.glyphicon-trash:before{content:"\e020"}.glyphicon-home:before{content:"\e021"}.glyphicon-file:before{content:"\e022"}.glyphicon-time:before{content:"\e023"}.glyphicon-road:before{content:"\e024"}.glyphicon-download-alt:before{content:"\e025"}.glyphicon-download:before{content:"\e026"}.glyphicon-upload:before{content:"\e027"}.glyphicon-inbox:before{content:"\e028"}.glyphicon-play-circle:before{content:"\e029"}.glyphicon-repeat:before{content:"\e030"}.glyphicon-refresh:before{content:"\e031"}.glyphicon-list-alt:before{content:"\e032"}.glyphicon-lock:before{content:"\e033"}.glyphicon-flag:before{content:"\e034"}.glyphicon-headphones:before{content:"\e035"}.glyphicon-volume-off:before{content:"\e036"}.glyphicon-volume-down:before{content:"\e037"}.glyphicon-volume-up:before{content:"\e038"}.glyphicon-qrcode:before{content:"\e039"}.glyphicon-barcode:before{content:"\e040"}.glyphicon-tag:before{content:"\e041"}.glyphicon-tags:before{content:"\e042"}.glyphicon-book:before{content:"\e043"}.glyphicon-bookmark:before{content:"\e044"}.glyphicon-print:before{content:"\e045"}.glyphicon-camera:before{content:"\e046"}.glyphicon-font:before{content:"\e047"}.glyphicon-bold:before{content:"\e048"}.glyphicon-italic:before{content:"\e049"}.glyphicon-text-height:before{content:"\e050"}.glyphicon-text-width:before{content:"\e051"}.glyphicon-align-left:before{content:"\e052"}.glyphicon-align-center:before{content:"\e053"}.glyphicon-align-right:before{content:"\e054"}.glyphicon-align-justify:before{content:"\e055"}.glyphicon-list:before{content:"\e056"}.glyphicon-indent-left:before{content:"\e057"}.glyphicon-indent-right:before{content:"\e058"}.glyphicon-facetime-video:before{content:"\e059"}.glyphicon-picture:before{content:"\e060"}.glyphicon-map-marker:before{content:"\e062"}.glyphicon-adjust:before{content:"\e063"}.glyphicon-tint:before{content:"\e064"}.glyphicon-edit:before{content:"\e065"}.glyphicon-share:before{content:"\e066"}.glyphicon-check:before{content:"\e067"}.glyphicon-move:before{content:"\e068"}.glyphicon-step-backward:before{content:"\e069"}.glyphicon-fast-backward:before{content:"\e070"}.glyphicon-backward:before{content:"\e071"}.glyphicon-play:before{content:"\e072"}.glyphicon-pause:before{content:"\e073"}.glyphicon-stop:before{content:"\e074"}.glyphicon-forward:before{content:"\e075"}.glyphicon-fast-forward:before{content:"\e076"}.glyphicon-step-forward:before{content:"\e077"}.glyphicon-eject:before{content:"\e078"}.glyphicon-chevron-left:before{content:"\e079"}.glyphicon-chevron-right:before{content:"\e080"}.glyphicon-plus-sign:before{content:"\e081"}.glyphicon-minus-sign:before{content:"\e082"}.glyphicon-remove-sign:before{content:"\e083"}.glyphicon-ok-sign:before{content:"\e084"}.glyphicon-question-sign:before{content:"\e085"}.glyphicon-info-sign:before{content:"\e086"}.glyphicon-screenshot:before{content:"\e087"}.glyphicon-remove-circle:before{content:"\e088"}.glyphicon-ok-circle:before{content:"\e089"}.glyphicon-ban-circle:before{content:"\e090"}.glyphicon-arrow-left:before{content:"\e091"}.glyphicon-arrow-right:before{content:"\e092"}.glyphicon-arrow-up:before{content:"\e093"}.glyphicon-arrow-down:before{content:"\e094"}.glyphicon-share-alt:before{content:"\e095"}.glyphicon-resize-full:before{content:"\e096"}.glyphicon-resize-small:before{content:"\e097"}.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before{content:"\e101"}.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102"}.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103"}.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\e104"}.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105"}.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106"}.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107"}.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108"}.glyphicon-calendar:before{content:"\e109"}.glyphicon-random:before{content:"\e110"}.glyphicon-comment:before{content:"\e111"}.glyphicon-magnet:before{content:"\e112"}.glyphicon-chevron-up:before{content:"\e113"}.glyphicon-chevron-down:before{content:"\e114"}.glyphicon-retweet:before{content:"\e115"}.glyphicon-shopping-cart:before{content:"\e116"}.glyphicon-folder-close:before{content:"\e117"}.glyphicon-folder-open:before{content:"\e118"}.glyphicon-resize-vertical:before{content:"\e119"}.glyphicon-resize-horizontal:before{content:"\e120"}.glyphicon-hdd:before{content:"\e121"}.glyphicon-bullhorn:before{content:"\e122"}.glyphicon-bell:before{content:"\e123"}.glyphicon-certificate:before{content:"\e124"}.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{content:"\e125"}.glyphicon-thumbs-down:before{content:"\e126"}.glyphicon-hand-right:before{content:"\e127"}.glyphicon-hand-left:before{content:"\e128"}.glyphicon-hand-up:before{content:"\e129"}.glyphicon-hand-down:before{content:"\e130"}.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right:before{content:"\e131"}.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left:before{content:"\e132"}.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up:before{content:"\e133"}.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down:before{content:"\e134"}.glyphicon-globe:before{content:"\e135"}.glyphicon-wrench:before{content:"\e136"}.glyphicon-tasks:before{content:"\e137"}.glyphicon-filter:before{content:"\e138"}.glyphicon-briefcase:before{content:"\e139"}.glyphicon-fullscreen:before{content:"\e140"}.glyphicon-dashboard:before{content:"\e141"}.glyphicon-paperclip:before{content:"\e142"}.glyphicon-heart-empty:before{content:"\e143"}.glyphicon-link:before{content:"\e144"}.glyphicon-phone:before{content:"\e145"}.glyphicon-pushpin:before{content:"\e146"}.glyphicon-usd:before{content:"\e148"}.glyphicon-gbp:before{content:"\e149"}.glyphicon-sort:before{content:"\e150"}.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet:before{content:"\e151"}.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt:before{content:"\e152"}.glyphicon-sort-by-order:before{content:"\e153"}.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt:before{content:"\e154"}.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes:before{content:"\e155"}.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt:before{content:"\e156"}.glyphicon-unchecked:before{content:"\e157"}.glyphicon-expand:before{content:"\e158"}.glyphicon-collapse-down:before{content:"\e159"}.glyphicon-collapse-up:before{content:"\e160"}.glyphicon-log-in:before{content:"\e161"}.glyphicon-flash:before{content:"\e162"}.glyphicon-log-out:before{content:"\e163"}.glyphicon-new-window:before{content:"\e164"}.glyphicon-record:before{content:"\e165"}.glyphicon-save:before{content:"\e166"}.glyphicon-open:before{content:"\e167"}.glyphicon-saved:before{content:"\e168"}.glyphicon-import:before{content:"\e169"}.glyphicon-export:before{content:"\e170"}.glyphicon-send:before{content:"\e171"}.glyphicon-floppy-disk:before{content:"\e172"}.glyphicon-floppy-saved:before{content:"\e173"}.glyphicon-floppy-remove:before{content:"\e174"}.glyphicon-floppy-save:before{content:"\e175"}.glyphicon-floppy-open:before{content:"\e176"}.glyphicon-credit-card:before{content:"\e177"}.glyphicon-transfer:before{content:"\e178"}.glyphicon-cutlery:before{content:"\e179"}.glyphicon-header:before{content:"\e180"}.glyphicon-compressed:before{content:"\e181"}.glyphicon-earphone:before{content:"\e182"}.glyphicon-phone-alt:before{content:"\e183"}.glyphicon-tower:before{content:"\e184"}.glyphicon-stats:before{content:"\e185"}.glyphicon-sd-video:before{content:"\e186"}.glyphicon-hd-video:before{content:"\e187"}.glyphicon-subtitles:before{content:"\e188"}.glyphicon-sound-stereo:before{content:"\e189"}.glyphicon-sound-dolby:before{content:"\e190"}.glyphicon-sound-5-1:before{content:"\e191"}.glyphicon-sound-6-1:before{content:"\e192"}.glyphicon-sound-7-1:before{content:"\e193"}.glyphicon-copyright-mark:before{content:"\e194"}.glyphicon-registration-mark:before{content:"\e195"}.glyphicon-cloud-download:before{content:"\e197"}.glyphicon-cloud-upload:before{content:"\e198"}.glyphicon-tree-conifer:before{content:"\e199"}.glyphicon-tree-deciduous:before{content:"\e200"}.glyphicon-cd:before{content:"\e201"}.glyphicon-save-file:before{content:"\e202"}.glyphicon-open-file:before{content:"\e203"}.glyphicon-level-up:before{content:"\e204"}.glyphicon-copy:before{content:"\e205"}.glyphicon-paste:before{content:"\e206"}.glyphicon-alert:before{content:"\e209"}.glyphicon-equalizer:before{content:"\e210"}.glyphicon-king:before{content:"\e211"}.glyphicon-queen:before{content:"\e212"}.glyphicon-pawn:before{content:"\e213"}.glyphicon-bishop:before{content:"\e214"}.glyphicon-knight:before{content:"\e215"}.glyphicon-baby-formula:before{content:"\e216"}.glyphicon-tent:before{content:"\26fa"}.glyphicon-blackboard:before{content:"\e218"}.glyphicon-bed:before{content:"\e219"}.glyphicon-apple:before{content:"\f8ff"}.glyphicon-erase:before{content:"\e221"}.glyphicon-hourglass:before{content:"\231b"}.glyphicon-lamp:before{content:"\e223"}.glyphicon-duplicate:before{content:"\e224"}.glyphicon-piggy-bank:before{content:"\e225"}.glyphicon-scissors:before{content:"\e226"}.glyphicon-bitcoin:before{content:"\e227"}.glyphicon-btc:before{content:"\e227"}.glyphicon-xbt:before{content:"\e227"}.glyphicon-yen:before{content:"\00a5"}.glyphicon-jpy:before{content:"\00a5"}.glyphicon-ruble:before{content:"\20bd"}.glyphicon-rub:before{content:"\20bd"}.glyphicon-scale:before{content:"\e230"}.glyphicon-ice-lolly:before{content:"\e231"}.glyphicon-ice-lolly-tasted:before{content:"\e232"}.glyphicon-education:before{content:"\e233"}.glyphicon-option-horizontal:before{content:"\e234"}.glyphicon-option-vertical:before{content:"\e235"}.glyphicon-menu-hamburger:before{content:"\e236"}.glyphicon-modal-window:before{content:"\e237"}.glyphicon-oil:before{content:"\e238"}.glyphicon-grain:before{content:"\e239"}.glyphicon-sunglasses:before{content:"\e240"}.glyphicon-text-size:before{content:"\e241"}.glyphicon-text-color:before{content:"\e242"}.glyphicon-text-background:before{content:"\e243"}.glyphicon-object-align-top:before{content:"\e244"}.glyphicon-object-align-bottom:before{content:"\e245"}.glyphicon-object-align-horizontal:before{content:"\e246"}.glyphicon-object-align-left:before{content:"\e247"}.glyphicon-object-align-vertical:before{content:"\e248"}.glyphicon-object-align-right:before{content:"\e249"}.glyphicon-triangle-right:before{content:"\e250"}.glyphicon-triangle-left:before{content:"\e251"}.glyphicon-triangle-bottom:before{content:"\e252"}.glyphicon-triangle-top:before{content:"\e253"}.glyphicon-console:before{content:"\e254"}.glyphicon-superscript:before{content:"\e255"}.glyphicon-subscript:before{content:"\e256"}.glyphicon-menu-left:before{content:"\e257"}.glyphicon-menu-right:before{content:"\e258"}.glyphicon-menu-down:before{content:"\e259"}.glyphicon-menu-up:before{content:"\e260"}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}html{font-size:10px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;background-color:#fff}input,button,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:focus{color:#23527c;text-decoration:underline}a:focus{outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}figure{margin:0}img{vertical-align:middle}.img-responsive{display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-rounded{border-radius:6px}.img-thumbnail{padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto}.img-circle{border-radius:50%}hr{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee}.sr-only{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;margin:-1px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0, 0, 0, 0);border:0}.sr-only-focusable:active,.sr-only-focusable:focus{position:static;width:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;clip:auto}[role="button"]{cursor:pointer}.container{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:750px}}@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:970px}}@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:1170px}}.container-fluid{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}.row{margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px}.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12{position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12{float:left}.col-xs-12{width:100%}.col-xs-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-xs-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-xs-9{width:75%}.col-xs-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-xs-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-xs-6{width:50%}.col-xs-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-xs-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-xs-3{width:25%}.col-xs-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-xs-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-12{right:100%}.col-xs-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-9{right:75%}.col-xs-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-6{right:50%}.col-xs-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-3{right:25%}.col-xs-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-xs-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-xs-pull-0{right:auto}.col-xs-push-12{left:100%}.col-xs-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-xs-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-xs-push-9{left:75%}.col-xs-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-xs-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-xs-push-6{left:50%}.col-xs-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-xs-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-xs-push-3{left:25%}.col-xs-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-xs-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-xs-push-0{left:auto}.col-xs-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-xs-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-xs-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-xs-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-xs-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-xs-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-xs-offset-0{margin-left:0}@media (min-width:768px){.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12{float:left}.col-sm-12{width:100%}.col-sm-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-sm-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-sm-9{width:75%}.col-sm-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-sm-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-sm-6{width:50%}.col-sm-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-sm-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-sm-3{width:25%}.col-sm-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-sm-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-12{right:100%}.col-sm-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-9{right:75%}.col-sm-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-6{right:50%}.col-sm-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-3{right:25%}.col-sm-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-sm-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-sm-pull-0{right:auto}.col-sm-push-12{left:100%}.col-sm-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-sm-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-sm-push-9{left:75%}.col-sm-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-sm-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-sm-push-6{left:50%}.col-sm-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-sm-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-sm-push-3{left:25%}.col-sm-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-sm-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-sm-push-0{left:auto}.col-sm-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-sm-offset-0{margin-left:0}}@media (min-width:992px){.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12{float:left}.col-md-12{width:100%}.col-md-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-md-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-md-9{width:75%}.col-md-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-md-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-md-6{width:50%}.col-md-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-md-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-md-3{width:25%}.col-md-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-md-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-md-pull-12{right:100%}.col-md-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-md-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-md-pull-9{right:75%}.col-md-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-md-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-md-pull-6{right:50%}.col-md-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-md-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-md-pull-3{right:25%}.col-md-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-md-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-md-pull-0{right:auto}.col-md-push-12{left:100%}.col-md-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-md-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-md-push-9{left:75%}.col-md-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-md-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-md-push-6{left:50%}.col-md-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-md-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-md-push-3{left:25%}.col-md-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-md-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-md-push-0{left:auto}.col-md-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-md-offset-0{margin-left:0}}@media (min-width:1200px){.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12{float:left}.col-lg-12{width:100%}.col-lg-11{width:91.66666667%}.col-lg-10{width:83.33333333%}.col-lg-9{width:75%}.col-lg-8{width:66.66666667%}.col-lg-7{width:58.33333333%}.col-lg-6{width:50%}.col-lg-5{width:41.66666667%}.col-lg-4{width:33.33333333%}.col-lg-3{width:25%}.col-lg-2{width:16.66666667%}.col-lg-1{width:8.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-12{right:100%}.col-lg-pull-11{right:91.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-10{right:83.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-9{right:75%}.col-lg-pull-8{right:66.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-7{right:58.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-6{right:50%}.col-lg-pull-5{right:41.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-4{right:33.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-3{right:25%}.col-lg-pull-2{right:16.66666667%}.col-lg-pull-1{right:8.33333333%}.col-lg-pull-0{right:auto}.col-lg-push-12{left:100%}.col-lg-push-11{left:91.66666667%}.col-lg-push-10{left:83.33333333%}.col-lg-push-9{left:75%}.col-lg-push-8{left:66.66666667%}.col-lg-push-7{left:58.33333333%}.col-lg-push-6{left:50%}.col-lg-push-5{left:41.66666667%}.col-lg-push-4{left:33.33333333%}.col-lg-push-3{left:25%}.col-lg-push-2{left:16.66666667%}.col-lg-push-1{left:8.33333333%}.col-lg-push-0{left:auto}.col-lg-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.66666667%}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333333%}.col-lg-offset-0{margin-left:0}}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after,.container:before,.container:after,.container-fluid:before,.container-fluid:after,.row:before,.row:after{content:" ";display:table}.clearfix:after,.container:after,.container-fluid:after,.row:after{clear:both}.center-block{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.pull-right{float:right !important}.pull-left{float:left !important}.hide{display:none !important}.show{display:block !important}.invisible{visibility:hidden}.text-hide{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}.hidden{display:none !important}.affix{position:fixed}
```

```html
<h2>This would be the initial structure</h2>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">Column 3</div>
 </div>
</div>



<h2>I need that in a mobile resolution the columns are organized in the following way, obviously without duplicating the HTML if not done automatically.</h2>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">Column 3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buenas amigo puedes hacerlo con la propiedad de `css` `display:flex`

los objetos flexibles puedes manipular su orden y asi ponerlo de primero o segundo como a merite el caso para tu solucion es necesario subir el bloque2 a la posicion 1 para hacer eso:

```
    .responsive li:nth-child(1){
    order:1;
   }
   .responsive li:nth-child(3){
    order:1
   }
```

> Por defecto, los elementos flexibles se presentan en el orden de origen. Sin embargo, la orderpropiedad controla el orden en que aparecen en el contenedor flexible.

**Ejemplo**

```
.item {
  order: <integer>; /* default is 0 */
}
```

---

**Ejemplo de "Diseño del Santo Gríal"**

Este ejemplo muestra como la "caja flexible" proporciona la habilidad de cambiar dinámicamente el diseño para distintas resoluciones de pantalla. El diagrama siguiente ilustra la transformación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se muestra el caso en que el diseño de la página adaptado a un navegador tiene que mostrarse óptimamente en un smartphone. No solamente los elementos se reducen de tamaño, sino que el orden en que se muestran también cambia. La "caja flexible" lo hace muy sencillo.

Fuente:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS) y [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

espero te ayude saludos.

```js
$("#cambiar").click(function(){
  $("ul").addClass("responsive")
})
```

```css
*{
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  ul li {
    width: calc(33% - 30px);
    margin:15px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgb(125, 223, 85);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  /*agregar cuando quieras el cambio en el responsive*/
  .responsive {
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  .responsive li:nth-child(2){
    width:100%;
  }
  .responsive li:nth-child(1){
    width:calc(50% - 30px);
  }
  .responsive li:nth-child(3){
    width:calc(50% - 30px);
  }
   
  .responsive li:nth-child(1){
    order:1;
  }
    .responsive li:nth-child(3){
    order:1
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Column1</li>
    <li>Column2</li>
    <li>Column3</li>
  </ul>
  
    <button id="cambiar" type="button" name="button">Cambiar Estructura</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para estos casos agregás más de una clase de columna a `div`

Las `xs` son para las pantallas mas pequeñas mientras que las `sm` serían las que le siguen.

Esto produce que cuando se ve en mobile la primer columna ocupe toda la línea (12) `col-xs-12` mientras que las otras dos ocupan la mitad cada una `col-xs-6` por lo tanto quedan con la forma que deseas, la primera arriba y las otras dos abajo una al lado de la otra.

Si lo ves de una pantalla más grande (no recuerdo bien el tamaño de los breakpoints de Bootstrap) se aplicarían las `sm` por lo que cada columna ocuparía un tercio (4 de 12) de la fila `col-sm-4` por lo tanto quedan las tres una al lado de la otra.

Podés cambiar `sm` por `md` o `lg`dependiendo de cuando necesites que las tres se vean contiguas.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
    Columna 1
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
    Columna 2
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
    Columna 3
  </div>
</div>
```